# Pandas duplicates when grouped

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

```
x = df.groupby(["Customer ID", "Category"]).sum().sort_values(by="VALUE", ascending=False)
```

I want to group by Customer ID but when I use above code, it duplicates customers...

Here is the result:

[image]

Source DF:

```
  Customer ID Category  Value
0           A        x      5
1           B        y      5
2           B        z      6
3           C        x      7
4           A        z      2
5           B        x      5
6           A        x      1
```

new: https://ufile.io/dpruz

Comment: I don't see any duplicates

Comment: Could you provide a small sample data set and your desired data set?

Comment: Please read [how to make good reproducible pandas examples](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) and edit your post correspondingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for something like this:

```
df_out = df.groupby(['Customer ID','Category']).sum()
df_out.reindex(df_out.sum(level=0).sort_values('Value', ascending=False).index,level=0)
```

Output:

```
                      Value
Customer ID Category       
B           x             5
            y             5
            z             6
A           x             6
            z             2
C           x             7
```

Comment: Yes Thanks. May I ask a question too please?

Comment: Can I get first 100 Customer ID? And can you give me the route to learn dataframe well? Thank you.

Comment: One way you could do it is to add .head(100) directly infront of .index above.  For example, let say I want the top 2 from this list of three. `df_out.reindex(df_out.sum(level=0).sort_values('Value', ascending=False).head(2).index,level=0)`

Comment: How do you learn dataframes well? Well, start answering questions on Stack Overflow.  Even if the answers have been accepted, answer them  yourself.  You will get better overtime.  Read the entire Pandas documentation and work through the examples.

Comment: You are awesome. Thanks.

Comment: @MaxU There has to be an easier way to sort multiindex level 0 by values.  Right?